# hibernate range query

Tags: hibernate, range

I want to do range query like ,

select u.age from user u where age between 10 and 20.  These 10 and 20 will be dynamic values.

I tried parameter as,

```
a=10;
b=20; 
Query q = session.createQuery("select u.age from user u where age between a and b");
q.setInteger("a",a);
q.setInteger("b",b);
```

This is giving me error. I am missing something after between word. Can anybody tell me how this can be achived ?

Comment: ure missing ":"s before a and b  , and  "u.age" instead of age. is this typo ? if so , try `select u.age from user u where u.age between :a and :b`

Answer (score 4):

The more optimal solution is using a hibernate Criteria, rather than hard-coded SQL queries. You should declare a @Entity annotation for your User class, and create private fields corresponding to the columns of your table.

Let's say you have a User table with an id, name, and age. The User class will then look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User{

    private long id;
    private String userName;
    private int age;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "userName", nullable = false)
    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    @Column(name = "age")
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
}
```

Note: if the columns in the database table have **exactly** the same name as your fields, the @Column (name = "..") annotation is not necessary.

Then, retrieving the age would be :

```
int userAge = session.createCriteria(User.class)
                         .add(Restrictions.ge("age", a))
                         .add(Restrictions.le("age", b))
                         .setProjection(Property.forName("age"))
                         .uniqueResult();
```

Creating a criteria by User class tells hibernate to make a **select from User** table. Then, the restrictions mean **where age >= a** and **age <= b**, respectively. The **uniqueResult()** tells hibernate that we expect a single result, while the projection is needed to retrieve a certain column (the projection there means **select age from User**). If no projection is specified, the criteria would return by default the entire class, i.e. a **select * from User**.

I know this seems a little too complicated for what you need, but working with entities that match your tables and with the Criteria is the right way to go.

Comment: I'm just learning Hibernate.  Why is Criteria better than HQL?

Comment: Through "better" I understand that it is a more programatically-correct approach. Hard-coding is never a good solution in anything. Take for example the case that your database changes (some tables change their column names, or table relationships, for example). Using the HQL would mean to enter all of your DAO classes (I am talking about a bigger application) and modifying each and every sql call so that it matches the new database and its relations. Using criteria would just require to enter the corresponding classes and do a rename(refactor) of the fields. This is just a very basic example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make named parameters.

```
a=10;
b=20; 
Query q = session.createQuery("select u.age from user u where age between :a and :b");
q.setInteger("a",a);
q.setInteger("b",b);
```